# Installing NetworkManager leaves Ubuntu 14.04 without Internet

Tags: 14.04, c++

I'm trying to use the NetworkManager library as a c++ library in order to add wifi support in a Linux app. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

I've tried nmcli through command line, but calling it with the app is not stable enough and prefer to use a pure c++ library.

I downloaded [NetworkManager](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/NetworkManager) version 1.4.2 "stable". After executing autogen.sh, and make & make install, the process ends successfully.

When I restart the machine, though, I can't access Internet. Neither with wired cable or with Wifi dongle.

Is this normal? What should I do if I want to use the library in my app?

Another problem detected is that in Settings/Network there is the following message "**The system network services are not compatible with this verison**".

I can't even use *nmcli* through command line anymore. This errors appears "**nmcli: error while loading shared libraries: libnm.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory**"

**Edit:** nmcli is solved using this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13428910/how-to-set-the-environmental-variable-ld-library-path-in-linux. It was needed to add the library path "/usr/local/lib.

Now I can scan for Wifi with nmcli in command line, but if I try to connect, this message appears: "**Error: Connection activation failed:(53) The Wi-Fi network could not be found**"

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Possibly 1.4.2 is just too far upstream to be compatible with your system (even 16.04 only has 1.2.x afaik). You might have been better off adding the appropriate source code repository (`deb-src`) so that you could then have used `apt-get` to install the appropriate (matching) version of the package source for your system.

Comment: I think you're right @steeldriver. The 14.04 version is 0.9.8.8. I will try to install this version and see what happens.

Comment: @steeldriver No luck.. I installed the version 0.9.8.8 and after restarting my internet is gone :/

Comment: Did you install 1.4.2 over system files (e.g. to `/usr/` rather than, say, `/usr/local`)? Are you sure you were able to remove all traces of it?

Comment: I'm using a VirtualMachine. Made a safe copy before installing 1.4.2. Before attemting to install 0.9.8.8 I had Internet. After the installation was complete, too. But **after restarting** the virtual machine, Internet gone.